# passing package.path variable to lua lanes

Tags: lua, lua-lanes

I wanted to pass `package.path` to lua lanes

```
Code Snippet below :-

package.path = package.path..";..\\Test\\?.lua"

local function lane1()
    ..
end


Thread1= lanes.gen("*",{globals = _G},lane1)

T1 = Thread1()
T2 = Thread2()

T1:join()
```

Is it possible for `package.path` to be part of lane1 by passing it as argument in `lanes.gen`?